# Не хватает строк множественного числа для цветов знака

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, знаки

Одни и те же строки используются для обозначения групп знаков и в строке про конкретный знак. Очевидно, что нужны разные наборы строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как формируется это сообщение:

[Tx:5068](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267051?key=9768feb3fdb1f267b06093bc572952dd)

> Gold
>   Золотые

[Tx:6068](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40840518?key=1b133144babbd04808205927bb6b8bc2)

> $badgeClass$ $tag$ tag badge
>   $badgeClass$ знак за метку $tag$